# How do I read the last "n" bytes of a file in Java

Tags: java, file, byte, bufferedreader

How do I read the last n number of bytes from a file, without using RandomAccessFile.

The last 6 bytes in my files contain crucial information when writing the files back. I need to write my original files, and then append the last 6 bytes elsewhere.

Any guidance? Thanks

Comment: I know that. I'm asking how to store the last bytes, instead of storing the whole file. I guess I can't get my head around the logic

Comment: Why won't you use `RandomAccessFile`?

Answer (score 5):

You have to do it by using [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).
Instances of this class support both reading and writing to a random access file. A random access file behaves like a large array of bytes stored in the file system.

```
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(your_file, "r");
randomAccessFile.seek(your_file.length() - n); 
randomAccessFile.read(byteArray, 0, n);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could implement an `OutputStream` that "decorates" your current stream by extending `FilterOutputStream` to preserves the last six bytes written. When writing is complete, query your custom decorator for the last six bytes.

The implementation could use a simple ring buffer that records all single-byte writes, or up to the last six bytes of each block write.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    fis.getChannel().position(fis.getChannel().size() - 6);
    byte[] a= new byte[6];
    fis.read(a);
```