# How to detect if BufferedInputStream was over while filling an array in Java?

Tags: java, file

```
    FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(path);
    BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
    byte[] inputByte1= new byte[500];
    byte[] inputByte2= new byte[500];
    byte[] inputByte3 =new byte[34];
    bin.read(inputByte1);
    bin.read(inputByte2);
    bin.read(inputByte3);
```

Let's say the file had only 400 bytes. How can I detect it?
I know that I could check if `(bin.read(inputByte1)!=500)`
But this looks really ugly to write in each line.

My main questions is:

**How to detect if before filling some array the buffer was done.**

I do not want to do `bin.read()` for each byte and check `bin.read!=-1`.

Comment: Search and read about BufferedReader class

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did, but I am more interested in a good way to loop through it, rather than having a lot of hard coded values.

Comment: For reading N bytes you could RandomAccessFile . Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20155829/how-do-i-read-the-last-n-bytes-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: Thanks for your response. But actually I want to read it sequentially and not load in memory.

Answer (score 1):

First, on a Windows based system you need to escape the `\` when you use it as a path separator. Next, you could use a [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) (which you could wrap with a [`BufferedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)). Finally, you should `close` the `InputStream` when you're done (or you risk leaking file handles, sockets or some other resource). You might use a [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Putting it all together, it might look something like

```
File f = new File("c:\\test\\test.txt");
try (InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f))) {
    int val;
    while ((val = is.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.println((byte) val);
    }
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a `DataInputStream` over a `BufferedInputStream` over a `FileInputStream`. That way you can use the `readFully()` method to read exactly as many bytes as you need each time without having to loop.

```
c:\test\test.txt
```

Use forward slashes in Java:

```
c:/test/test.txt
```